# Pytorch: test loss becoming nan after some iteration

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train a deep learning architecture, the model trains perfectly. I am testing after each epoch. For 7 epoch all the loss and accuracy seems okay but at 8 epoch during the testing test loss becomes nan. I have checked my data, it got no nan. Also my test accuracy is higher than train which is weird. Train data size is 37646 and test is 18932 so it should be enough. Before becoming nan test started to become very high around 1.6513713663602217e+30. This is really weird and I don't understand why is happening. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: your network is divergent, reduce learning rate...

Comment: Not working reduced learning rate from 0.05 to 0.001 but still getting nan in test loss as during testing one module of my architecture is giving nan score at epoch 3 after some iteration. Separately the module works fine but when I incorporate one module in to the other to add their score this thing is happening

Comment: how did you calculate loss? If you add loss every time you loop through the data in the batch, it will most probably lead to nan, instead, you need to calculate your loss by adding it every time a batch is forwarded through the network.

Comment: As its a test phase I don't add loss at each batch, instead I am appending them to separate variable to get the final mean loss after the iteration through batches ends.

Comment: @SaniaZahan, could you add your code to your question?

Comment: @yakhyo unfortunately my model is too large. And the NaN issue is solved after I changed my optimizer from SGD to Adam though I am not sure why!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that a very high learning rate isn't the cause of the problem, you can clip your gradients before the update, using PyTorch's `gradient clipping`.

Example:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()        
loss, hidden = model(data, hidden, targets)
loss.backward()

torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_value)
optimizer.step()
```

This is the first thing to do when you have a NaN loss, if of course you have made sure than you don't have NaNs elsewhere, e.g. in your input features. I have made use of gradient clipping in cases where increasing the learning rate caused NaNs, but still wanted to test a higher learning rate. Decreasing the learning rate could also solve your problem, but I'm guessing that you have already tried this.

Empirically, I set `clip_value = 5` most of the times, and then see its (usually non-significant) impact on performance. Feel free to experiment with different values.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I did try reducing learning rate and gradient clipping. Still got nan in the test loss. Then I changed my SGD (with momentum 0.9) to Adam. Now the nan issue is no more and all seems good for now. Though I am confused why this should be. I read somewhere that SGD with momentum works better than Adam.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if I set my gradient clip value too high say 25 then will it hurt performance too much

Comment: It's great that it worked. I really don't know why SGD produced nan and adam not. About performance, I think that ADAM is better in most cases than SGD, but that's up to experimentation and depends on the problem. About your gradient clip value, no, I don't think that setting it too high will hurt performance, but the opposite; its impact will be lesser (fewer values clipped). Happy coding. ^^

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really confused how to set the clip value as pytorch doc didn't quite help.

Comment: really effective！